# How to get the modern PayPal recurring subscription page

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I'm trying to integrate recurring subscriptions for PayPal and it's working fine but the problem is I'm getting the old "outdated" PayPal look. I've looked around on Stackoverflow but haven't found a valid answer that solves this issue.

[image]

The look I actually want when setting up recurring subscriptions is this (Example from another website)

[image]

Is there any HTML form variables that I can use or is it a different type of checkout with a subscription service? I'm looking all over to try and find a solution but I'm drowned in documentation.

Comment: Tried reading the documentation?

Comment: Yes @Akintunde007. Couldn't find anything.

Comment: Please email to tech-support of PayPal with exact scenario  they can give you the actual reason: support@paypal-techsupport.com